# Rational translates of the unit circle cover the plane

Tags: geometry, analysis

Is it true that the translations of the unit circle by vectors
with both coordinates rational cover the plane?

This comes to solving
$$ x=a+\cos \theta, \ y=b+\sin \theta$$
with unknowns $a,b$ rational and $\theta$
between $0,2\pi$.

I couldn't find a positive answer or an immediate contradiction.

(I typed the question from a phone
so if I made new tags by error, please correct them)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are only countably many rational translates of the unit circle $S^1\subset{\mathbb R}^2$. Altogether they make up a set of measure zero.

Comment: Nice, quick argument.

Answer (score 4):

No, the above statement is false.This is because it would imply that every real number is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Indeed, it follows that $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=1$